# Почему не могу поймать ошибку?

Tags: java

Всем привет. Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть код который делит число на ноль. Но программа не может поймать ошибку. Как решить? Сможете помочь?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            int x = 0;
            int y = 5/x;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("erekshe zhagdai");
        }
        catch (ArithmeticException ae)
        {
            System.out.println("arithmetikalyk zhagdai");
        }
        System.out.println("ayaktaldy");
    } 
}
```

Это ошибка при компиляций:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ArithmeticException  наследует класс Exception, поменяйте местами. Пишет же, что такая ошибка уже была словлена.

Comment: @entithat если словил, почему не выводит сообщение?

Comment: Код просто не скомпилируется. Ошибка ведь, мол нельзя сначала ловить родительский класс ошибки, а потом класс, который наследует. Поменяйте Exception и ArithmeticException местами

Comment: @entithat Спасибо) Сработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка вылетает по той причине, что ты написал неправильную последовательность перехвата исключений. Типы исключений должны идти от более специализированных к более общим. *ArithmeticException* наследуется от *Exception*, поэтому тебе в консоль и выводится, что это исключение уже поймано в блоке catch (Exception e). Просто поменяй порядок блоков catch и программа будет работать до конца без ошибок.

```
//сначала это
catch (ArithmeticException e)
{ System.out.println("ArithmeticException"); }

//потом это
catch (Exception e)
{ System.out.println("Exception"); }
```